# Create Folder If Non Existent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I need to check if a folder exists and if it does not create it.  So if `C:\CSV\red\` does not exist create, and so on.  I use this DDL - how can I create folder if not there?

```
Create Table bonniebell
(
   name varchar(max)
)

Insert Into bonniebell values ('red'), ('blue'), ('green')

Declare @foldername varchar(max), @fulldirname varchar(max)

Declare folder cursor for

  Select name
  from bonniebell
  order by name asc

  Open folder

  fetch next from folder into @foldername

  while @@fetch_status = 0
  Begin

    Set @fulldirname = "C:\CSV\"

    Set @fulldirname = @fulldirname + @folder

  Fetch Next from folder into @foldername

  END

Close folder

Deallocate folder
```

Comment: use xp_cmdshell to make the directory

Comment: @WEI_DBA - how do I check if already exists?  will xp_cmdshell overwrite if already exist?

Comment: If it already exists, it will return output saying that it exists. It won't error out.

Comment: @WEI_DBA - can I catch the error so my script will continue to progress?  I do not want it to halt on an existing directory.

Comment: Capture the output. That will give you the results. If it's Null, then it was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the extended stored proc "xp_dirtree".  Store the results in a temp table and get the rowcount.  Zero = not exists.

```
create table #Files(
subdirectory nvarchar(512),
depth int)

insert into #Files
exec xp_dirtree 'c:\windowsX'

select @@ROWCOUNT

drop table #Files
```

Answer (score 2):

[xp_cmdshell is disabled by default, there are risks if you enable it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/157863/21924)

Unless you really need to know if it exists first, use:

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir 'C:\CSV\red\'
```

- If it does not exist it will create it
- If it does exist it won't change anything, nor error out

I tested using SSMS, where I had existing items in the folder, no issues.

I did not test with an SP

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the xp_cmdshell making a directory.

```
  Exec master..xp_cmdshell 'mkdir d:\temp'
```